# The 'arguments' object cannot be referenced in an arrow function in ES3 and ES5. Consider using a standard function expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, arrow-functions

Currently building a sample whiteboard project and faced a typescript issue

```
var format = (formatString, ...params: any[]): string => {
    var i = 0;

    while (/%s/.test(formatString)) {
        formatString = formatString.replace('%s', arguments[++i])  --> Error at (arguments)

    }
    return formatString;
};
```

I checked the similar issue over stack overflow but didn't get a concrete answer

Comment: Kindly help me out

Comment: What's your `.tsconfig` es target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the availability of rest parameters feature in JS an in typescript.

The fact that [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object is used for functions with variable number of parameters in ES3 & ES5 should not make you use it in typescript.

For functions with variable number of parameters in typescript, you should use [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters). Typescript compiler will compile it to:

- [Js rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) with ES2015 target
- arguments object with ES3 or ES5 target

```
var format = (formatString: string, ...params: any[]): string => {
    var i = 0;

    while (/%s/.test(formatString)) {
        formatString = formatString.replace('%s', params[i++]);

    }
    return formatString;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/LAKAbghgTgBAZgeygWwgFxgXhgCkS9AZTSgEsA7AcwC4YBnEiygGhgDoOAHaCZO2iOQCeAbQC6ASloMyVLAD4YAb1Aw1MSLFJYYABgDcq9QHcAFqQA2AU1wB6AKR1bbNFYZ4kqNMVmUJE5SN1dXwvHyYdUKJGKjYoK04LCABjKxwAckd01m4oXjoRAGpC0klDECCYAF9K+LQAVyhyeE9o33Kq8tBkhHI6BGs2CwRKDwI0DIgYRxgAI2m6GGSFtWyYAEZWACZWAGZ-fSA)